# How to save other languages in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, hindi

Hi I have to save hindi languages in mysql. how can I do that. any one knows the solution please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to store all text as UTF8, then you'll be able to see Hindi characters. You can update a column to use UTF8 with a query like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE posts MODIFY title VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

Since you use PHP, make sure that all your PHP scripts are saved as UTF8. You can also set the [connection charset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) with the following query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

This will ensure that your web server and database servers communicate using UTF8.

Comment: If the data is already stored in a non-utf8 column, you need to insert new data.